# make -k with Android NDK

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, makefile

With `make`, I can do a `make -k` to cause the compiler to try compiling every file that can be tried, to show me as many compilation errors as possible. How do I do the equivalent with `ndk-build` in the Android NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndk-build pass all the arguments to make, so `ndk-build -k` should work.

Answer (score 2):

The `ndk-build` is a wrapper around GNU Make. If you `cat ndk-build` you will see the code of the script.

So, you can pass options to the command as if you were using `make`. For instance, if you type `ndk-build -h`, the script will print the make help.